# Improving speed of sampling of a custom SciPy distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, scipy

I am trying to implement a custom probability density function that is based on combinations of chi2 distribution shifted by a parameter A, and flipped logistic function shifted by a parameter B.

Kernel of the above probability density function:

$\LARGE\frac{(x-A)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-A)}}{1+e^{D(x-B)}}$

This expression has additional parameters - `k` which would be `df` in chi-square distribution, and parameter `D`, and both give me flexibility in the shape of my curve. For example, for `A=2, B=4, df=2.7, D = 3`, the function looks like this:

[image: Function]

I can implement that in Python by inheriting from `scipy.stats.rv_continuous`. Additionally, I can make sure that the integral of my function is 1 by implementing caching (memoization) and scipy.quad (which finds integral of a function). Then I just have to divide it by that constant. The code that creates an instance of my custom function is defined below.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import functools
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.integrate import quad

class custom_kernel(st.rv_continuous): #this is with cached property AND with overloaded _cdf
    @functools.cached_property
    def z(self):
        """Integral from A  to B """
        z = quad(self._phoney_function,self.loc,self.end)[0]
        return(z)
    
    def __init__(self,A,B,df,D):
        """
        A = loc parameter
        B = end parameter
        df = degrees of freedom for chisquare
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.a = A
        self.b = B
        self.loc = self.a
        self.end = self.b
        self.df = df
        self.D = D

    def _pdf(self,x):
        y = self._custom_chiker(x)*self._supplemental_logistic(x)/self.z
        return(y)
    
    def _phoney_function(self,x):
        """just used for quick z calculation"""
        y = self._custom_chiker(x)*self._supplemental_logistic(x)
        return(y)
    
    def _custom_chiker(self,x):
        y = (x-self.loc)**(self.df/2-1)*np.exp(-0.5*(x-self.loc))
        return(y)
    def _supplemental_logistic(self,x):
        y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(self.D*(x - self.end),dtype=np.float64))
        return(y)
    
A = 2
B = 4
df = 3
D = 2

custom = custom_kernel(A=A,B=B,df=df,D=D)
```

Now, if I want to sample from my custom, all I need to do is call `samples = custom.rvs(size=100)` or any other size. Timing it, I've got 792 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop, which isn't bad, but isn't good. For example, sampling it from chi2.rvs with the same size takes 57.1 µs ± 218 ns per loop which is roughly a thousand times faster. Per the following [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html), if I want to improve the speed of sampling, I either need to overwrite _ppf (or _cdf), or include sampling on _rvs.

I have no idea how I could implement any of these things. I do not know how to compute cdf of my function by hand, and I have no idea how to implement a fast integral of it.
[The following question, related to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751076/advice-on-speeding-up-scipy-custom-distribution-sampling-fitting), has an answer that I can sample from kernel density estimation of probability distribution. I also have no idea how I would implement that.

Anyone have a clue how I can improve my sampling speed?

(Question is posted here, rather than Stack Overflow, because CV has LaTeX support)

EDIT : I'd like to generate random numbers according to a chi square distribution with defined degrees of freedom parameter. But the gist is that I want that chi square distribution to be within $[A,B]$ where $A>0$ and $B>A$. For example, the graph below:

[image: Graph]

I can do that in scipy by feeding `loc=2` to `scipy.stats.chi2.pdf`. I don't know how to make it 0 to the right of B (for $x>B$)

Comment: (1) Your formula is incomplete: it *must* specify that $x$ is restricted to the interval $[A,B].$ (2) There are a huge number of possible solutions, depending on the likely values of the parameters. Please specify the possible ranges of all the parameters $A,B,D,k$ in your formula. (3) Please explain what you mean by "implement." The question sounds like you just want to sample from this distribution, but it mentions other aspects of it, such as its distribution function. (4) Speed depends partly on intended usage. For instance, do you intend to draw huge samples for a given set of parameters?

Comment: (1)
Why would my formula need to specify that $x$ must be between A and B? From the graph provided, values for x can be below A and above B.
(2)
My only constraint (I'll edit that) is that parameter B is greater than parameter A (usually around twice of A). I dont have any constraints on parameters D and K. What exactly do you mean when by "huge number of possible solutions"

Comment: (3/4)
I have defined a function that between A and B has a distinct shape depending on D and k, and is 0 everywhere else. I want to create a large number of samples, or *numbers* from this function. I just want that.

Comment: If you don't restrict $x$ to some such interval, you haven't defined a valid pdf.  In fact, unless $k$ is an even integer, your formula isn't even defined for $x\lt A.$  By "huge number of possible solutions" I mean the many techniques found by searching our site for [random number generation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+number+generat*). They range from Monte-Carlo to rejection sampling to antithetical sampling to piecewise linear approximation to inverting the quantile function and on and on.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help. Two questions.

1) If restriction is necessary for a valid pdf, how come I can still generate data even for cases where $x$ <A, as evidenced from the above graph?

2) Reframing my question to "generate tons of numbers from the above mentioned formula", is there anything you technique you can recommend. 

Thanks for the clarification, I'm going to go search the site for some answers.

Comment: Which technique to recommend depends on the likely values of the parameters you will be using--that's why I asked.  I don't understand your comment about generating data with $x\lt A,$ because your plots show that *no* values were less than $A=2.$  If somehow your software did produce such values, it did so erroneously.

Comment: Well, I can feed the function a value less than A, and it will spit out zero. Just for example, if I use scipy's chi2 pdf on a negative value, I will get zero.  How does that work?

Also, my x are between parameters A and B. The main reason for the denominator part (and parameter D) is because it's just chi-square function, and I don't know how to limit it for x>B.

Ideally, my parameters k are larger than 2, but smaller than 7, while D is larger than 5 but smaller than 10.

Comment: You are not distinguishing *generating random values* from *computing the PDF.*  Which is it you want to do??

Comment: Generate random values

Comment: Then your previous comment isn't germane: "Spit out zero" is computing the PDF, not generating random variables.

Comment: @ivan199415 - learning is hard.  whuber is solid, and half of that is having deep understanding while the other half is not pulling any punches.  to become as powerful as a bear, you have to get mauled by the bear and survive.  ;)